# Understanding principal component analysis with k-means clustering

Tags: python, pandas, k-means, pca

I have a visualization that plot k means clusters with Principal Component Analysis (PCA) values.
From my understanding. PCA is an algorithm to reduce the large set of data to smaller one so that we can visualize better.

Can i interprete my visualization as most of the data are similar to each other which is why they cluster around each other?

Or is my understand of PCA with K means clustering is wrong?
[image]

Comment: This does not seems a python related question.

Answer (score 0):

PCA projects the initial feature space into a lower dimensional one. Be careful though, after applying PCA the features are not the initial ones, but the eigenvectors. That is why PCA falls into the category of *Feature Transformation*.

Concerning your question, it seems that taking the first two eigenvectors (aka the ones with the largest eigenvalues) did not help. However, I would recommend to try the following before jumping to the conclusion of "*my data cannot be clustered*":

- PCA is a linear transformation. Your data may be more complicated than you have anticipated, therefore, you would need to introduce some non-linearity. This means that you should train an AutoEncoder in order to project your data into a lower dimensional space
- K-means produces spherical clusters of the same radius more or less. This may easily not be the case for your data. Try other algorithms like  Gaussian Mixture Models or DBSCAN
- try 3D. Introduce the third eigenvector and plot in 3D. You may be surprised to find that your data is separable after all

> I saw 3 clusters, be careful on how you decide on the number of clusters as well.